# lags number in multivariate time series analysis correlation

Tags: time-series, correlation, forecasting

I am trying to calculate the correlation coefficient(Pearson's r) of a financial time series $Y(t)$ and other exogenous variables $X_1(t),..., X_n(t)$. I am trying to understand the impact of my exogenous variables in my target variable.
I am wondering if I sould calculate Pearson's r between $Y(t)$ and $X_1(t),...,X_n(t)$ or with $X_1(t-i),...,X_n(t-i)$ (lagged values of exogenous variables) and if so, how can I determine the timesteps of lagged values ($i$)